# Bootstrap Switch JS being called, but doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and jQuery, but I'm currently trying to add in Bootstrap Switch. I'm starting to go insance because I cannot get it to work. From inspecting the element, it looks as though the js isn't modifying any html.

I've tried using either the gem or the straight js/css. I tried both sass and css from the gem. No matter what it looks like the js isn't doing anything. If I remove the bootstrap-switch js file then I get an error (which makes sense), so I know it's getting called. It just doesn't do anything.

Below is pieces of my setup:

#### Gems

```
Using sass (3.3.2)
Using bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
Using bootstrap-switch-rails (2.0.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
```

#### Application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap3-switch";
```

#### Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//
//= require_tree .
```

#### other.js

```
$("#famous-people-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
```

#### some.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="famous-people-switch" type="checkbox" name="famous-people" checked>
  <h4>Famous People:</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements are loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#famous-people-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

Comment: I think I'm going to cry. I forget to do this way too often. I'll accept when I can

Comment: I posted a very similar question about the event handler not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461748/bootstrap-switch-event-handler-not-working