# Bootstrap Switch Event Handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I asked a question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460608/bootstrap-switch-js-being-called-but-doing-nothing) but now I'm stuck on using Bootstrap Switch's [event handler](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#event-handler).  I want to just print out the state when the switch gets toggled. Currently it only switches the state when clicked and does not trigger the new event.

Below is some of my setup:

#### some.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#famous-people-switch").bootstrapSwitch();

  $("#famous-people-switch").on("switchChange", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.value);
  });
});
```

#### some.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="famous-people-switch" type="checkbox" name="famous-people" checked>
  <h4>Famous People:</h4>
</div>
```

#### Gems

```
Using sass (3.3.2)
Using bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
Using bootstrap-switch-rails (2.0.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
```

#### Application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap3-switch";
```

#### Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/S52bm/.  Note that you have a couple errors in your HTML: 1) "checked" is not a minimized attribute, it must be `checked="checked"` and 2) `<input />` is a self-closing tag and therefore needs the forward slash at the end.

Comment: @TNguyen Could there be a problem with my rails setup? I updated the html to be valid and it still doesn't work. The it becomes a Bootstrap Switch toggle button, but the event handler isn't working.

Comment: This smells like a syntax error or configuration issue but without more details, it would be hard for anyone here to nail down the exact problem.  Have you tried other events?  Have you also set a breakpoint in the code to see if it reaches the `console.log` statement?

Comment: I think I've found the issue. It looks like the gem I'm using (bootstrap-switch-rails) hasn't updated to version 3. I'm forking and submitting a pull request to fix it! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is not being triggered due to the version of bootstrap-switch. Version 2 does not include them and the gem currently only supports Version 2. I've submitted a pull request to update the gem to version 3 (still being developed).

**Branch w/ Version 3**: https://github.com/tomprats/bootstrap-switch-rails/tree/allow-switch-v3

**Pull request**: https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/bootstrap-switch-rails/pull/9

**Usage**

Update your Gemfile to use the correct branch:

```
gem "bootstrap-switch-rails", git: "git://github.com/tomprats/bootstrap-switch-rails, branch: "allow-switch-v3"
```

Update your Application.js file:

```
//= require bootstrap-switch3
```

Update your Application.css file:

```
*= require bootstrap-switch3
```

Or Application.css.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-switch3";
```